# Load text file in powershell and process data

Tags: powershell, text

I was delivered a text file with tens of millions of data.
CSV has limitations and could not be used. An example text file is shown below, all separated by tabs.

```
fileUrl   fileExtension   filePath   fileType   name   ownerName  
https://????.[sharepoint.com/sites/aaa_bbb/Shared%20Documents/General/%EC.xlsx](sharepoint.com/sites/aaa_bbb/Shared%20Documents/General/%EC.xlsx)   xlsx   /sites/aaa_bbb/Shared Documents/General/filepath CheckSheet List.xlsx   \[2, 'SPREADSHEET'\]   2023 CheckSheet List.xlsx   UserPrincipalName  
https://????.[sharepoint.com/sites/aaa_bbb/Shared%20Documents/General/%EF.xlsx](sharepoint.com/sites/aaa_bbb/Shared%20Documents/General/%EF.xlsx)   xlsx   /sites/aaa_bbb/Shared Documents/General/filepath CheckSheet List2.xlsx   \[2, 'SPREADSHEET'\]   2023 CheckSheet List.xlsx   UserPrincipalName
```

What I want is below.

1. 1. Load the text file using PowerShell. Encoding is required.
$source= Get-Content D:\result.txt -Encoding utf8

2. Add each row.
"fileUrl","fileExtension","filePath","fileType","name","ownerName","PowerShell_rt"

3. Add the tab-separated values ​​one after the other. Examples have been ~ processed, but all content must be included.

```
fileUrl   fileExtension   filePath   fileType   name   ownerName  
\------   --------------   --------   ---------   ------   --------------  
URL\~    xlsx      Path\~      2, 'SPREADSHEET'   name\~ UPN\~
```

4. Execute the Get command by referring to the value of fileUrl, and save D among the results of A,B,C,D to PowerShell_rt.

Get-Spomodule -fileurl $_.fileurl
A id : aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd
B : path : file/path/www.xlsx
C : rabel : non
D : active : non

5. Save the results to a new text file.

```
fileUrl   fileExtension   filePath   fileType   name   ownerName   PowerShell_rt  
\------   --------------   --------   ---------   ------   -------------- ----------------  
URL\~    xlsx      Path\~      2, 'SPREADSHEET'   name\~ UPN\~ Result
```

Getting the values ​​from a text file into rows is also too difficult. The content may be long and complicated, but it is earnest.
If you help me, I will cooperate as much as I can with the part that I don't understand. please.

Comment: You are showing two rows of data here. You are going got need RegEx for the use case. Load a sanitized version of your file into Regex101.com and parse the string, then use that regex in your script. You can use *.csv with this data after you come up with the correct regex. Just coping a paste your sample dataset into notepad, shows it is just space delimited. There are tons of articles and samples all over SO, and the web shows plenty of examples of how to do this. Just know that millions of rows will take a long while to process.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to SO. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: To get you started a simple replace statement, ConvertFrom-Csv, and Export-Csv should get you what you are after.

Comment: Do not try to do every thing in one step.  So you can start with : $csv = Get-Content D:\result.txt -Encoding utf8 | ImportCsv -Delimiter `t

Comment: hi, thanks everyone for the replies
I want to use import-csv, but I can't use it with more than 1 million rows.
If you use a text file, can't you put tab-separated values into a specific variable as a loop?
Should I only work with csv?